# How does this setter end up working? (ListView MultiSelect)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resharper

I have a ViewModel which I'm using as an `ItemsSource` for a `ListView`, that implements an interface called `ISelectable`:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// An interface that should be implemented by a ViewModel that can be 
/// marked as selected, when multiple selections are allowed.
/// </summary>
public interface ISelectable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is selected.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// <c>true</c> if this instance is selected; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

The `ListView` is showing search results of a "search clients" feature, so all items are `ClientViewModel` instances - and `ClientViewModel` implements `ISelectable` so has a `IsSelected` property:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="SearchResultsList" ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ClientViewModel}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This works perfectly; in the window's ViewModel I can define a property like this:

```cs
public IEnumerable<ClientViewModel> SelectedClients 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return _searchResults == null 
                              ? null 
                              : _searchResults.Where(e => e.IsSelected); 
    } 
}
```

And I get what I'm expecting.

The question I have is about the below part of the XAML - the designer underlines `IsSelected` in the `Value="{Binding}"` part and says "Cannot resolve property 'IsSelected' in data context of type [type of the window's ViewModel]":

```xml
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

- How can I tell the designer that the data context for `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` should be the same as that of the data template?
- How does it end up working at run-time, if the XAML designer says it can't be resolved?

---

### UPDATE

This is a ReSharper warning. I could switch it off, but what I want to know is *how does the setter end up working*, because I get correct auto-complete for this:

```xml
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ClientViewModel}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" /> <!-- "Name" is available from IntelliSense -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

But not for that:

```xml
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" /> 
            <!-- "IsSelected" isn't, IntelliSense is showing the members of the Window's ViewModel -->
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: the XAML designer isn't that smart, I guess. You can try setting the `d:DataContext` property in either the `Style`, or the `Setter`. I'm not sure it will work, though.

Comment: did it still shows the error once you build your project?

Comment: @nit yes it does. I should say it's highlighting in blue, ...and that I have ReSharper 7.1 running, not sure how to switch off XAML parsing with R# to make sure it's not R# being misleading here...

Comment: it will be Resharper as i never saw default designer intellisense pointing this type of error in Binding experssion

Comment: Right. Looks like a R# glitch, I can edit inspection options for "unresolved symbol in static context" and if I turn it to "hint" the underline turns into a R# hint. Definitely ReSharper. Seeing as my options to specify a context don't go below the `ListView` I guess my only option is to ignore this warning... which is annoying because R# is otherwise generally very accurate.

Comment: @retailcoder I think it's a bug of the `IDE`, I have also experienced some similar bugs. That's fairly annoying.

Comment: @retailcoder have you tried setting `d:DataContext`?

Comment: @retailcoder I'm not sure if the `XAML` interpreter interprets the `XAML` code in order (from top to bottom) but you should try swapping the position of `<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>...` and `<ListView.ItemTemplate>...`?

Comment: @HighCore yes, but it says `d:DataContext` can't be attached to elements of type 'Style' or 'Setter'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the Resharper doing the trick as i never saw default designer intellisense pointing this type of error in Binding experssion. You can switch of the Resharper completly to proof it completly.

since you are setting property inside ListViewItem style and you are using {Binding IsSelected}, it will search IsSelected in the DataContext of each listviewitem which is your ClientViewModel and that has IsSelected property...hence binding is perfect.. the designer is not smart enough to prob this deep

Comment: It is a R# thing.. but I still want to understand what's going on here for the binding to work, since the native VS designer is giving me auto-complete for members of the window's ViewModel, not members of type of the `ItemsSource` - in other words yes it's a R# warning, but it's accurate as far as I can tell.

Comment: since you are setting property inside ListViewItem style and you are using {Binding IsSelected}, it will search IsSelected in the DataContext of each listviewitem which is your ClientViewModel and that has IsSelected property...hence binding is perfect.. the designer is not smart enough to prob this deep