# Visual studio does not recognize the correct type for data binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, resharper

Here is a small example that i created to illustrate my problem.

```
public class DataItem
{
    public DataItem() {}
    public DataItem(bool isSelected)
    {
        IsSelected = isSelected;
    }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}


public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<DataItem> {new DataItem(true), new DataItem()};
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The XAML is:

```
<Window x:Class="RoomDesigner.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:RoomDesigner.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="350"
        Width="525"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModel:MainViewModel}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="299" Margin="230,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" 
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>  <!--This line-->
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsSelected}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This example works as expected: a selected item always has `True` written in it, and `False` is written in an unselected item.

However, Visual Studio (or Resharper) underlines the word `IsSelected` on the marked line and the suggestion says `Cannot resolve property 'IsSelected' in data context of type 'RoomDesigner.ViewModel.MainViewModel'`. It wants to bind to a `MainViewModel` and not to `DataItem` somewhy.

I use Visual Studio 13 SP3 and Resharper 8.1.

I'd like to know where this strange behavior comes from and if there is a way to fix it, because it is kind of annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the d:DataContext on the Style element. It is not inferenced automatically for ItemContainerStyle property.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModel:DataItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>  <!--This line-->
</Style>
```

See a similar question: [Specify datacontext type on listbox ItemContainer in style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231120/specify-datacontext-type-on-listbox-itemcontainer-in-style).
Another similar question: [How does this setter end up working? (ListView MultiSelect)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100882/how-does-this-setter-end-up-working-listview-multiselect).